# CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+C Is not working for me

Tags: transforms, 3d-cursor

I have a model I need to rotate around the center. I have put the 3D cursor in the center of the grid. I've hit the hot keys and selected "Origin to 3D cursor" but it does not move. At least not while my current object is selected.

If I unselect the current object it does it, but when I select the object again, it goes way back up into space again.

Comment: Can you post your .blend?

Comment: Ctrl Shift Alt C moves the *Object origin*. I suspect you are trying to adjust the *Manipulator*, in which case try pressing `.` (period).

Comment: are you by any chance using a linux system? some desktop environment capture the alt key globally and interfere with programs that use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont have to change the origin point to rotate around the 3D cursor,
just change the pivot point in the 3D view header to "3D Cursor"

The Blender Reference Manual covers this here:

https://www.blender.org/manual/de/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/pivot_point/index.html

Comment: Incidentally, I was doing something stupid. I had left a lamp up in the sky beyond where I could see it. When I was selecting all, it was selecting it too and so it was putting the origin between my intended object and the lamp. Thanks for the answers, everyone.